# Code Keeps opening an Untitled-1 file every time I open the app

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everytime I open Visual Studio Code, the app loads up and randomly opens a file called "Untitled-1" which contains the following snippet of code:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

I want to open up Visual Studio Code without it opening any file at all at load. I just want the window to open with nothing loaded. I've set all of these settings, but it still happens.

```
"window.reopenFolders":"none",
"window.openFilesInNewWindow":"off",
"window.openFoldersInNewWindow":"off"
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: possibly related: [How do I get rid of a persistent VS Code 'Dirty Editor'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60317437/11107541)

Answer (score 7):

Your globals are probably set to `"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile"`

Try chaning this setting to `none` or removing it all together.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to "hot exit".

Try adding this to your settings:

```
"files.hotExit": "off"
```

To read details about hot exit, check out the official announcement [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/30/hot-exit-in-insiders).

Comment: When Untitled-1 is not Empty, VScode will alert user to save it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the backup folder from your `Code` data folder. On macOS that is in application support.