# How do I get rid of a persistent VS Code 'Dirty Editor'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running VS Code on OSX, and whenever I open VS Code I am presented with a bit of text I must have pasted in a code window as a clipboard buffer and cannot seem to prevent it from doing so!

My usual workflow opens code by launching a workspace file, and when doing this I get two VS Code windows, one with my project (from the workspace file) and another with the text snippet in.

(Opening VS Code by the application launcher I just get a window with the text in it)

If I 'cold quit' (CMD+Q), I get the following error message on the 'non project' text window.

```
One or many editors that are dirty could not be saved to the backup location.
Try saving or reverting the dirty editors first and then try again.
```

I've tried saving the text as a file and closing the window but it just appears as a new file in the next window again.

I can get rid of the window, by either closing it and saying no to saving the text, or saving it - but it will just appear again next time I open VS Code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have been running into this problem for a month or so now and finally figured it out. The backup folder was somehow owned by root so VSC couldn't write/update/delete. I just had to chown the backup folder back to my user. You can find the folder at: /Users/x/Library/ApplicationSupport/Code/Backups

Comment: Oh my gosh - thank you thank you thank you !!!! - It was a directory under my Backup directory, but once chown'd restarted, quite the horrible dirty editor, that folder disappeared and HAS NOT OPENED AGAIN!!!! WAA!!! THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Tried this but not working for remote vscode session. See similar experience documented here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/mjrcsx/dirty_editor_and_lost_code/