# VScode : dirty editors is taking long time to save

Tags: python

could you help me t understand what is dirty editors and how I can solve this problem so I can run my code and exit from VS
thank u .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get rid of a VSCode 'Dirty Editor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60317437/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-vscode-dirty-editor)

Comment: @shy-tan  no unfortunately it doesn't help